# How to prevent unwanted usage of pubnub credentials

Tags: credentials, pubnub

I am using pubnub SDK (php/JS) and struggle to understand the following:

IN JS the pubnub credentials are visible to ANYBODY. Now I am not concerned about who reads and writes to channels. But how do I prevent that other peple simply copy my pubnub credentials and use them in their OWN projects/websites?

My users do not need to login, so I am not sure how I would use PAM to prevent the above.

Comment: The keys you speak of are meant to be publicly accessible.  The only key that you can not expose is the `SECRET KEY`.  That must stay secret.  Using PubNub Access Manager you can grant access to authenticated users.  You must BYO authentication.  You can use Google OAuth, Twitter OAuth or build your own using MongoDB or MySQL.  Once you've verified the user/password, you can grant an access token to the user.

Comment: If you want, you can grant a 1 time token that lasts forever.  You can give your non-authentecated users this forever token.  That way in the future you can choose to revoke the token.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Secure Access

> "My users do not need to login"

If you want, you can grant a one-time token that lasts forever. You can give your non-authenticated users this forever token. That way in the future you can choose to revoke the token.  You can generate the token using the [PubNub Developer Console](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/console).

Essentially you still need to give each user a token even if they’re not authenticating.  They have to check-in with your application even if you don’t know who they are.

Ideally each user gets their own `auth_key`.  But since you don't authenticate identity, you can give each user the *same* `auth_key`.  This way you can generate a new key anytime you need to and revoke old users anytime you want.

Your API Keys are meant to be public.  This is a good thing.  The only key that must remain hidden is the `Secret Key`.  The Secret Key should never be transmitted or shared.  You should not save the secret key on a device, app, code or code repository.  You should keep this key secret because it allows you to grant access to your users.  If your secret key is exposed contact support@pubnub.com to change your secret key.  You can also regenerate the key yourself.  You can grant tokens that authorize users when you have the secret key.  The tokens allow granular read and write access controls at the user level.

### Tutorial for PubNub Access Manager

> A good place to start.

Start here - [Access Manager Getting Started Guide](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/getting-started-guides/pubnub-access-manager) - Fine grain access control for streams of data by person, device or channel in a few simple steps with PubNub Access Manager.

[image: Access Manager Starting Guide]

- [Access Manager provides token-based authorization allowing granular read and write access.](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/security/access-manager/)
- [JavaScript V4 Security Tutorial - Access Control](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security)

> Diagram below shows devices with `auth_key` access tokens.  The "Customer Data Center" holds the **Secret Key**.  The secret key is used to generate the `auth_key` tokens.

[image: PubNub Access Manager for User Level Security Controls]

> Follow the steps starting with your servers to generate and exchange the `auth_key` access tokens for your users.

[image: PubNub access manager security]

Comment: I am generating a token based on the SessionID everytime a user comes by. As the token is based on the SessionID it stays the same for every visit during that session (to avoid billing me the same user/device multiple times). I am generating the token like this, for example: Would that be a correct way to use PAM server side? $pubnub = new Pubnub($pubkey,$subkey,$seckey',false,false,false,false,session_id()); $pubnub->grant(true, true, 'someRoom',session_id(),240);

Comment: I think you are confusing auth-key with UUID. We bill by UUID. Each visitor should generate a UUID, store it in localStorage to reuse for future visits. auth-keys can change and there is no affect to billing.

Comment: Without a login, this is difficult to control. It would be the same as giving insert/update/read access to your database through a web app. No login means no security. So this is not just a PubNub thing. You can let all visitors subscribe but don’t let them publish. If you want to allow publish then have a really tight UI that restricts which channels they publish to and have your server publish it on behalf of the visitors. So that at least prevents publish key abuse.

Comment: It works now, but what pubnub completely fails to tell: If you subscribe to a channel WITH PRESENCE, then you MANUALLY need to grant access to the presence channel of a channel as well. Example. If you want to subscribe to channel "foo" with presence, you need to grant access to "foo" AND "foo-pnpres". I haven't found this crucial information anywhere.

Comment: Craig: My account is billed by IP, that's why I do not care so much about the UUID.

Comment: Fair feedback on granting to -pnpres and I am filing a request to document this and possibly add to your API to "grant withPresence". The UUID was a minor point but do know that it is very important to Presence.